# AWS Secret Key Manager-How to retrieve secret value out from SecretString

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, secret-key

I am storing my database password into the Secret value field in the aws secret manager. How do I retrieve the secret value out if I am using the following code?

Secret Key defined in secret key manager: Keykey
Secret value defined in secret key manager : dbPwd

```
GetSecretValueResponse response = null;
response = client.GetSecretValueAsync(request).Result;
LogWriter.IEConnectLogEvent("GetSecretAsync : " + response.SecretString, "GetSecretAsync");
```

The above will give me this value : {"Keykey" :"dbPwd"} when I write into a log file. May I know how do I extract the dbPwd out ? Thank you.

Comment: Is code on client or server?  If code is on server how do you expect to get the key on the server?  Do you have a front end and a backend?  The backend connects to the database and the key need to be on the server (backend) and not the frontend.

Comment: @jdweng That has no link to the question. Please refrain from leaving comments that can further confuse the OP and other readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you receive a JSON value back from the secret manager, you can use a JSON deserializer to retrieve the key value.

Option 1:

```
var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.SecretString);
var dbPwd= data["Keykey"].Value<string>();
```

Option 2:

```
var secretString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SecretString>(response.SecretString);
var dbPwd = secretString.Keykey;

class SecretString
{
   public string Keykey { get; set;}
}
```